# Adding a UITableView as a Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to create a view that has a UITableView as only part of that view.  I believe this is the correct pattern when creating from code (not interface builder) but please feel free to add suggestions if my approach is wrong as well.

The exception I am getting is:
***[KBSMoreViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance***

I have a class header as below (I am implementing the constructor in the implementation):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface KBSMoreTableView : UITableView 
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style;
@end
```

I then have a ViewController class header as:

```
@interface KBSMoreViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@end
```

The ViewController, which is part of a tab bar and works fine (outside of the tableview I am trying to add) implementation is written as:

```
#import "../Models/KBSMoreTableView.h"

@interface KBSMoreViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) KBSMoreTableView* tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* cellIdentifier;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *source;

@end

@implementation KBSMoreViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:0];
        self.source = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Test1", @"Test2", nil];
        self.cellIdentifier = @"MoreCellId";
    }
    return self;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.source.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.source[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView = [[KBSMoreTableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is very clear. You don't implement the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` table view data source method. Instead, you have created a method named `numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Change this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was so obvious.  Apologies for the simple question, just starting out with Objective-C development.  Thanks for the quick reply.  Could you also comment on the actual approach I am using here? Is this proper design?